# How to transform list with index numbers

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list which looks like this:

```
{1,2,1,2,1,2}
```

I want to transform it into list that looks like this:

```
{{1,1},{2,2},{3,1},{4,2},{5,1},{6,2}}
```

Where the first element in the index of item in the list, and the second element is the element of the list.

How do I do this in Mathematica?

Comment: look up `MapIndexed` in the docs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
MapIndexed[Append[#2, #] &, {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2}]
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}, {6, 2}}

Also

```
MapIndexed[Reverse@Flatten[{##}] &, {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2}]
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}, {6, 2}}

```
Transpose[{Range @ Length @ #, #}] &@{1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2}
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}, {6, 2}}

```
Module[{i = 1}, {i++, #} & /@ {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2}]
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}, {6, 2}}

Answer (score 5):

```
Thread[List[Range@Length@list, list]]
```

or

```
MapThread[{#, #2} &, {Range@Length@list, list}]
```